# IOS, tableview filtering select with a search control

Tags: iphone, ios, search, uisearchbar, tableview

I am building a tableview list with a search control to filter it. My requirement is to let user select one cell quickly by input some keywords.

The UI is simple, a navigationbar with an OK button to confirm the selection, a searchbar below the navigationbar, and the tableview in the bottom.

The problem is that, when user try to filter the tableview, the navigationbar would be disappear, the whole screen will go to search mode, the searchbar would in the top of the screen. In that case, when user selected a cell, he/she could not click the OK button I put in the navigation bar to confirm the selection, he/she have to hit the cancel button of the search bar to exist the search mode and then click the OK button I put there. That is not I want to.

How can I deal with this, to make this operation more easier for my user?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try UISearchDisplayController ? It works like an autocomplete box.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
A search display controller manages display of a search bar and a table view that displays the results of a search of data managed by another view controller.
```

Example:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848

Hope this helps.